# Caching ignores rtrim

Tags: blocks, cache

I am trying to add canonical links **with trailing forward slashes removed** to my site's blog pages via:

```
<?php 
$currentUrl = rtrim(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'/');
$blogUrl = rtrim($this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('blog/blog')->getBlogUrl(),'/');

if ($currentUrl == $blogUrl) : ?>
    <title><?php echo $blogHelper->getTitle() ?></title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $blogUrl ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't want to rewrite Magento's getUrl method, so I figured I could just remove trailing forward slashes with `rtrim`.

However, whenever I turn on "Blocks HTML Output" caching in Magento admin, the forward slashes return!

What I want:

```
mysite.com/blog
```

What I'm getting:

```
mysite.com/blog/
```

What's going on here and how can I fix it?

**EDIT :**

I thought this could be a problem with the getBlockSingleton method, so I tried using a model instead, via a getSingleton method, and still had the same problem: rtrim gets ignored.

Even `rtrim($blogUrl,'/')` (i.e. using rtrim *again*) gets ignored.

Solved the problem by building the URL up using the base url and a helper:

```
$blogUrl = rtrim($this->getBaseUrl().Mage::helper('blog')->getRoute(),'/');
```

The rtrim was unneeded there but I used it just in case.

Comment: I gather you also cleared your cache, after enabling it?

Comment: most definitely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't find the root cause of this problem, but, copied from my Edit above,

I solved the problem by building the URL up using the base url and a helper:

`$blogUrl = rtrim($this->getBaseUrl().Mage::helper('blog')->getRoute(),'/');`

The rtrim was unneeded there but I used it just in case.